# JavaScript not recognizing new NodeChildren

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6

Soo, I'm working on a project, which sohould read and write to a MSSQL database.

You should be able to insert a new Job, along with some steps.

I have a function to add more steps. The "Add Step" Button gets replaced with a new div with a new ID, puts a "remove" Button behind it and then it adds the button again. That seems like a pretty smooth way for me. But if you add a new step, the values in all the inputs get lost

[Before adding new Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2gtI.png)

[After adding a new Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1C8F.png)

Here's the code which executes when you add a Step:

```js
async function StepBtnHinzufügen()
{
  document.getElementById("stepbtn").outerHTML = '<div id="step'+stepctr+'"><br>StepNr: <input type="number" style="width: 40px;" value="'+(stepctr+1)*10+'" class="stepnr" id="stepnr'+stepctr+'"> | Program: <input style="width: 160px;" class="stepprogram" id="stepprogram'+stepctr+'"> | Variante: <input style="width: 80px;" class="varnr" id="varnr'+stepctr+'" > | Step User: <input style="width: 120px;" class="stepusr" id="stepusr'+stepctr+'"><button type="button" onclick="RemoveStep('+stepctr+');" class="btn btn-outline-danger">x</button>';
  document.getElementById("step").innerHTML += '<button type="button" id="stepbtn" onclick="StepBtnHinzufügen();" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="button">Step hinzufügen</button>';
  stepctr++;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("stepusr").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("stepusr"+i).innerHTML = Username;
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me why that happens and how there is a way to fix it?

I appreciate any help

Comment: you have to share html also, not just js..

Comment: When you use `.innerHTML` it *replaces* the existing HTML.  Use append methods instead.